# Aquery https images not getting loaded

Tags: android

I have image requests coming from internet over https link.

When I set the Imageview using the Aquery, I dont see the images loading.

No image is shown.

But image is getting loaded, once u use http link.

Please let me know, if anyone has the info.

Thanks
Harisha

code snippet

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width,height));

        AQuery aq = new AQuery(mContext);
        ApplicationProperty prop = new ApplicationProperty(mContext);
        aq.progress(-1).id(imageView).image(prop.getIpAddress()+"/"+rowItems.get(position).getImageURL(), true, true, 0, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN, AQuery.RATIO_PRESERVE);
        convertView = imageView;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Because I have the same problem with https :(

Comment: You cannot use Aquery for fetching images from https server. Instead I used imageLoader class written by developed posted on website

Comment: @harisha Can you link where you've found that info - about not being able to use aquery with https for images?

Comment: I tried loading the image from https website, image was not loaded. Note: https access need to validate SSL certificates.